# WPF publish application files

Tags: wpf, dll, publish

I am trying to publish a `WPF` application using the publish section in the project properties. When I attempt to specify application files (i.e. references) for the publish, I see lots of *old* dlls that were once in the project but were deleted later.

Is there a way to clean up this list so that it matches the references *actually* used in the project ?

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** possible without extensions. However you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157066/removing-all-unused-references-from-a-project-in-visual-studio-projects) question for more details. There are also some extensions listed you could use.