# View dlls called by executing program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017

I am developing a customised version of an application with the vast majority of the functionality taken out, to the point that it only has two use cases.

In its original form, this is quite a large application, with hundreds of required dlls. However, I believe I won't require most of them because of the limited functionality of my customised version, and so I want to take them out.

Is there a way I can run my application, and using the debugger or something, see which libraries are called by the application, so I can take out the rest?

**Edit**
This is not a duplicate of [Removing all unused references from a project in Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157066)

Whereas that shows how to remove all references which are not used by the code, what I want is the references that are used at run-time. In other words, if I take my application through my specific use cases - which will be the only two available to the user - which are required.

I could remove all the code that is not required by my application but that would be an unfeasibly massive job, so I'm settling for cutting down on the size of my application just by removing any dlls that won't ever be required because of how the user will use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all unused references from a project in Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157066/removing-all-unused-references-from-a-project-in-visual-studio-projects)

Have a look into the linked Question. It doesn't exactly answer your question, but i believe it solves your problem.

Comment: Debug > Windows > Modules lists the DLLs you actually use.

Comment: @HansPassant - I believe this is it... If you make it an actual answer I can accept.