# .NET Core self-contained publish references - how to remove unused?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm new to .NET Core. I've published a self-contained version of a test program which runs a simple TCP server, to `linux-x64`. However, when I publish it, the result is 70MB of the whole SDK. I can remove many of them, and their references within `*.deps.json`, without the program falling over, so I feel there's a lot of unused references. Is there a tool, or a different method of deployment, which is leaner?

The reason for this is I would like to have an alternate deployment method for a board with only 60MB space - removing Mono and using a native .NET Core program would fit the bill nicely.

Thank you.

Edit: This question is not a duplicate as Resharper's "Optimise References" is unavailable on .NET Core projects. Also, the other VS Extensions only seem to work up to VS2011.

Edit2: I've solved the problem, using .NET Core's [ILLinker](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51327.optimizing-footprint-of-net-core-applications.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing all unused references from a project in Visual Studio projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157066/removing-all-unused-references-from-a-project-in-visual-studio-projects)

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/30 .NET IL Linker is the only official tool today. .NET Core 3.0 is supposed to provide a new tool, but not yet fully uncovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem: using ILLinker and the instructions provided [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51327.optimizing-footprint-of-net-core-applications.aspx).

It removes not only unused DLL's, but dead code within those DLL's. Initially I didn't get it working, but that article worked.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know, there is no standard solution for it. But there are some solution!

The first is the Visual Studio Extension, which is removed the not used references, it called [Reference Assistant](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LarditeGroup.ReferenceAssistantforVisualStudio2010) And the second one is the [ReSharper](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JetBrains.ReSharper). The Resgharper is complex extension which has this functionality and many others.

And here is the littel decsription how the resharper works: [Remove Unused References With Reshaprer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Remove_Unused_References.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not removing packages but unused code: within `.NET Core 3.1` you can use the `-p:PublishTrimmed=true` argument with your publish command:

```
dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win81-x64 -p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

In my case this significantly reduced (about a third) the size of the `publish` folder.

Information can be found here: https://github.com/mono/linker/blob/master/docs/illink-tasks.md

**But** note their warning you see in the output: `Optimizing assemblies for size, which may change the behavior of the app. Be sure to test after publishing. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink`